# My computer will not recognize that python exists

Tags: snow-leopard, python

I have opened python on my somewhat outdated Mac OS X in Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and although it was working fine earlier, my computer will not recognize that I am using python.  When I click on the python window, instead of saying python in the upper left of the screen it will just say the last application I have been using, also, it will not let me type or do anything.  Also it will not quit unless I force quit it.  Python will work fine when I open it, the bug only starts when I open a new window.
If it helps when I open the shell it gives me this message:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

****************************************************************
Personal firewall software may warn about the connection IDLE
makes to its subprocess using this computer's internal loopback
interface.  This connection is not visible on any external
interface and no data is sent to or received from the Internet.
****************************************************************

IDLE 2.6.1
```

I am not sure that this is the right forum to post this in and hopefully I have provided useful information.

~~~Droonkid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an old bug, see [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6864). They basically recommend installing and using a newer version of python. Depending on whats using python you might want to get a newer version 2 release and not go all the way to the newest version 3 release.

Comment: You also need an up to date Tcl/Tk https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: I will upvote your answer as soon as I get enough reputation!